# NodeJS - Throw inside nested loop in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm new in NodeJS and Sails.js. I get stuck when run API script like here :

```
try{
 for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
  for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    await doSomething(); // asume the API using async
    throw 'a';  
  }
 }
} catch (e) {
 return e;
}
```

When I run the first time the script it's ok (running well), but when I run the second time, it is stuck (nothing return). When I check the console, no error appears.

It will work again if I restart the API.

> What happens to my script ? can anyone explain? Why it just run 1 time (return a) but cannot started again when i call again the API without restart it first

Comment: Could you add more code? For what i see it should always return `a`.

Comment: that's the point, i just return 'a'. But it just working when i first time run. When the second time. It's stuck (if i'm not restarting the API)

Comment: what if You remove `try...catch` block? most of web frameworks can handle throwing errors automatically

Comment: i want to break at throw line when it found data invalid.

Comment: it will be broken just try to remove try..catch, just keep:  `for(let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
  for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    await doSomething(); 
    throw 'a';  
  }
}`

Comment: @Crocodile have You checked for errors in terminal when loop broken for the first time? I suspect You've error in some place of code or in Your method that You think it's been broken by Your throw. Can You provide more details about Your code? How You've defined handler and etc.

Comment: Btw, why not just do: `return res.serverError('a');` instead of `throw` ?

Comment: @Crocodile `but cannot started again when i call again the API without restart it first`  Your app crashes somewhere (maybe inside of `doSomething()` method, maybe somewhere above or below of Your code), please give more details

Comment: Sorry but not error appear in console. I just try sails.log('aaaaa') at first line (it called). But stuck when enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you should throw Error not a string, so your could should look like this

```
throw new Error('a')
```

also the script won't continue after first loop cause you are throwing.

Comment: yes. but not my question. Return is in catch run. But just 1 time. When you try the script again. It hang on top of script.

Comment: the throw inside first loop will prevent other loop iterations from running, so if that what you want, your error would return from this function.

Comment: in fact sails understands when You just throw something. there is no need to catch it and return it

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not stuck. It will return the string `'a'`. You can check that by adding `console.log`

```
try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            throw 'a';
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: ', e);
    return e;
}
```

This will print `Error: a` all the time and `return 'a'`

Note: As mentioned you should `throw new Error` instead of string `'a'`.

If you want to break the loop on condition. Just set `i = 11; j = 11`;

Comment: he wants to break execution of loop. it's not the question how to throw

Comment: Throwing the error breaks the loop. Its not the question. Op said the loop is stuck

Comment: I think Op does not provide all details. seems like web app is crashing in some part that we don't know

Comment: `throw` will break the loop and return the value. That is the only output we can suggest with the available input.

Comment: I think Op has error in code that makes app crash, that's why web app does not respond for request second time. and the error which Op get's in terminal may be error of problem in the code.

Comment: Op said: `but cannot started again when i call again the API without restart it first`  - he has failure in his code that crashes the app.

Comment: Yes, i want to break the loop and return 'a'. But the first try , API return 'a', but when the second try (without restart) , it's stuck (no error in console too).

Comment: My temporary solution is using global variable such as var isSuccess = true;, and throw section replace by isSuccess = false; and then after all looping has done i add if(isSuccess) {} else {} ... but why i think use the throw before? because i think it's consume too much resource (example i loop 10000 datas), but actual already failed in index 1. It's not efficient i think.